# Not able to find free Ubuntu Pro tokens

Tags: upgrade

I have been owning an Ubuntu Pro Desktop subscription but I am not able to find the free tokens on my dashboard to add one more laptop to my subscription. Thanks in advance.

Screenshot removed for security reasons.

Comment: Please remove the screenshot. You don't want to show everyone your token!!!!

Comment: I don't know why the dashboard says "Your subscription is about to expire" and "1 machine" instead of "5". You may have to ask Canonical directly.